# O que acontece quando me registro em uma tag?

Tags: suporte, tags

Estava a olhar e percebi que é possível receber notícias sobre novas perguntas com uma tag específica, mas de qual modo o registrante é contactado que uma nova pergunta foi criada com essa tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recebe o e-mail de confirmação

Cujo o conteúdo é o seguinte: (ainda em inglês)

> ## Confirm your filter subscription
>
> You've chosen to receive email updates on new questions tagged
> "javafx".
>
> **Confirm Subscription**
>
> Email frequency: **every day**
>
> Once you've confirmed, you should receive your first email within 24
> hours (if there are new questions). To change the email frequency or
> your email address, visit [stackexchange.com/filters/142236/javafx](http://stackexchange.com/filters/142236/javafx?subscribe=yee-haw).
>
> Questions? Comments? Let us know on our feedback site. If you no
> longer want to receive mail from Stack Exchange, unsubscribe from all
> stackexchange.com emails.
>
> Stack Exchange, Inc.

Caso clicar no link para confirmar o seu registro poderá editar o seu filtro no link indicado no e-mail, neste exemplo seria:

http://stackexchange.com/filters/142236/javafx?subscribe=yee-haw

O padrão é receber e-mails com as atualizações (novas perguntas) todos os dias, mas pode trocar por uma frequência maior:

> every 15 minutes  | a cada 15 minutos
>
> every 3 hours     | a cada 3 horas
>
> every day         | todos os dias

Comment: Não seria mais interessante sermos avisados aqui na caixa de entrada do Stack Exchange? Não sei se alguém abre o e-mail apenas para verificar se alguém fez uma pergunta com a tag.

Comment: @Patrick isso é **status-by-design** e o objetivo é justamente comunicar os usuários que não estejam no site da Stack Exchange que existem atualizações nos tópicos em que eles possuem interesse.  

Por exemplo se possui smartphone e coloca para ser atualizado a cada 15min sempre receberá notificações sobre as atualizações na tag que segue (*claro que isso depende da popularidade da mesma*).

Comment: Mas aí o usuário concordou em receber atualizações a cada 15 minutos, eu por exemplo, dependendo da tag, gostaria de receber atualizações sempre que uma nova pergunta for postada.

Comment: Isto seria muito problemático para o SE em questão de banda considerando as tags populares como java que possui mais de 100 perguntas/dia no SOEN e possivelmente chegará neste nível aqui. Não teria como enviar 100 e-mails por dia e isso não ir para o seu SPAM.

E deve ser por e-mail pois se estiver no site pode configurar a sua página inicial com as Tags favoritas e as ignoradas.

Comment: Você pode ser quiser solicitar um [tag:novo-recurso] pedindo atualizações a cada pergunta. Mas não sei se terá força para convencer a comunidade.

Comment: Esse esquema de tags favoritas eu já uso, porém eu não sei quando uma nova pergunta com a tag é postada, eu tenho que clicar na tag e ver, manualmente.

Comment: Por que não usa [RSS](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/debate)?

Comment: Esse seu link de RSS está bugado, aparece apenas o html.

Comment: Não sei qual browser está usando mas funciona no Firefox, Opera, Maxthron. [Se estiver no Chrome precisa de um addon](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rss-feed-reader/pnjaodmkngahhkoihejjehlcdlnohgmp)